# variable specific to only one instance of a 2sxc app

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

My case:
I have a 2sxc app that displays a calendar. But I manage a sport club with 3 locations and I would like an event calendar for each locations. These 3 instances have to be in the same page and I have to switch the data according to the club.

I thought I could setup a variable in the app settings (Configuration or Resources) and use it like that :

```
@App.Settings.Club or @App.Resources.Club
```

but these data seems to be there for all the instances of the app in the same zone (portal).

I know I can distinguish the apps with @App.AppGuid or @App.AppId but all the **instances** have the same Id and I can't use the PageId as they are in the same page.

The only way I found is to use the title of the DNN module and use `@Dnn.Module.ModuleTitle` to have the information but it is not the best.

So, how can I distinguish the instances of the same app?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use the ModuleId - I believe it's @Dnn.Module.ModuleID (ID or Id, I'm not sure).

Or even better - just use the list-functionality instead of using the data-functionality. that way the items are already assigned to this instance. For this, enable "List" on the view.